# Correct usage of Clojure for macro

Tags: clojure

There are 100 buffaloes on the field.
There are 100 whisks on the field.
Each standing buffalo eats 5 whisks.
Each lying buffalo eats 3 whisks.
Each 3 old buffaloes eat 1 whisks.
How many buffaloes of each type are there on the filed?

This is my Clojure code to solve this problem:

```
;; s: number of Standing buffaloes
;; l: number of Lying buffaloes
;; o: number of Old buffaloes
(for [s (range 101) l (range 101) o (range 101)
      :while (and 
              (= 100 (+ s l o)
               (= 100 (+ (* s 5) (* l 3) (* o 1/3)))))]
     [s l o])
```

My code doesn't work. It should return how many buffaloes of each type but my code only returns an empty sequence. It seems to be logically incorrect. What's wrong with it?

Comment: This is way too vague. What about it doesn't work? Have you debugged it? I also don't know if a for loop is the best tool for the job here. I think you're confusing Clojure's for loop with a typical imperative for loop. Clojure's for loop is like Python's list comprehension.

Comment: Doesn't work means: incorrect result. It should return how many standing, lying, old buffaloes there are on the field. But my code only returns an empty sequence. It's logically incorrect.

Comment: Again, I don't think a for loop is appropriate here. You use a for loop when you want to produce a list of something. That's its main use case. That doesn't sound like what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Why not? I created a list of possible result. For example, there can be 8 standing buffaloes or 10 or 11 or whatever. The possible result is from 0 to 100. Hence (range 101).

Comment: Don't you just want to produce 3 values? 1 for each type of buffalo? The `loop`/`recur` pattern seems more appropriate.

Comment: Firstly, my code is very declarative => means it's very readable and very easy to understand. How can loop/recur be easier to understand than this? Secondly, I don't know how to write it with loop/recur for now.

Comment: Because it might actually get you the correct answer. Subjectively nice looking code isn't of much use if it doesn't work; look has nothing to do with the question. If you are producing more than 1 possible solution, a for loop may actually be appropriate. I was under the impression the code was looking for a single answer. My bad. As for why this code doesn't work, you're saying you only want to produce values while s + l + o is equal to 100. That will fail in the first iteration though, since 0 + 0 + 0 != 100, which will cause the loop to stop. Do you maybe mean `:when` instead of `:while`?

Comment: Also, note the missing bracket at the end of `(= 100 (+ s l o)`. That should probably be `(= 100 (+ s l o)) `, since I boolean will never be equal to a number.

Comment: I tried :when, the same empty sequence is returned.

Comment: Note my second suggestion under my long comment. You're missing a parenthesis. If you're writing this in IntelliJ/Cursive, you need to make sure the 2 `(= 100` forms are vertically aligned. In the way you have it now, the `and` isn't doing anything, and you're. Comparing boolean and numbers together.

Comment: okay, that's correct, I must use :when and put one more closing parentheses in. Would you mind writing your answer in the "answer" zone so that I can choose it to be the correct answer?

Comment: Added. Sorry I was argumentative. I had only woken up a few minutes before. I should have allowed my brain to engage first before commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 main issues:

- By using `:while`, you're telling it to stop searching as soon as the condition returns false. I believe your intent was to skip cases where the condition is false. For that, you use `:when`.
- Your condition has a misplaced brace, causing you to compare booleans and numbers, which is always false. Add a brace at the end of `(= 100 (+ s l o)`. If you're using Cursive to write this, make sure you vertically align forms so Parinfer can manage braces for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment**

Having taken [@Carcigentate's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169616/1562315) to *make it right*, you can *make it fast*er thus:

```
(for [s (range 101), l (range (- 101 s)) :let [o (- 100 s l)]
      :when (= 100 (+ (* s 5) (* l 3) (* o 1/3)))]
     [s l o])
```

Comment: Good suggestion. That should significantly cut down the search time. I'm actually curious now what the improvement is! Maybe I'll run these through Criterium.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I make it a factor of 200: `o` takes tbe one correct value out of 100; and the naive solution wastes on average half the 100 values of of `s`.

Comment: 47.955795 ms vs 3.831184 ms.

Comment: Then 37.532622 ms vs 3.741322 ms on another test. So ~10-12x.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The arithmetic must be fairly expensive. I was just counting cases.